# How to set the items/numbers in my array to integers?

Tags: python, arrays, integer, int

I would like to add items to my array, but these items should be integers. I would need to explain each line of code, so please detailed answers.

I have a suitcase and want to add items into it. **So far, I have got this:**

```
suitcase = [] #This should set the list of what is in my suitcase, to empty.

suitcase.append("sunglasses") #This will add the item 'sunglasses' to my empty array making it contain 1 item.

suitcase[0] = "1" #Now I want to change the item of sunglasses to an integer so I can later add it.
```

How do I set this item to an integer? Would I write 1 = "1" or do I have to write int("1")? I don't really understand the int function...

Thanks

Comment: How about just `suitcase[0] = 1`?

Comment: why not use enumerate?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen do would that be set as an integer or just a string? Can I add certain items in my array to other items and will use them to calculate it as an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is extremely unclear as to what your ultimate goal in this task is.

For example, it makes sense for a suitcase to contain sunglasses, but it doesn't make sense for a suitcase to contain 1!!!

One option, is that you're supposed to store items in a suitcase, and **map each one of them to an integer**. This can be achieved with a dictionary.

Example #1:

```
suitcase = {'sunglasses':1,'toothbrush':2}
```

Example #2:

```
suitcase = {'sunglasses':1}
suitcase['toothbrush'] = 2
```

Example #3:

```
suitcase = {}
suitcase['sunglasses'] = 1
suitcase['toothbrush'] = 2
```

You can then use each item in order to retrieve the integer that is mapped to it.

For example, `x = suitcase['sunglasses']` will set the variable `x` to the value `1`.

Another option, is that you're supposed to store items in a suitcase, and **map an integer to each one of them**. This can also be achieved with a dictionary.

Example #1:

```
suitcase = {1:'sunglasses',2:'toothbrush'}
```

Example #2:

```
suitcase = {1:'sunglasses'}
suitcase[2] = 'toothbrush'
```

Example #3:

```
suitcase = {}
suitcase[1] = 'sunglasses'
suitcase[2] = 'toothbrush'
```

You can then use each integer in order to retrieve the item that is mapped to it.

For example, `x = suitcase[1]` will set the variable `x` to the value `'sunglasses'`.

For more details on dictionaries, see http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping.

Comment: Thanks, so mapping is the best idea? What I am trying to do is assign an integer to a string (sunglasses) so if I type sunglasses + toothbrush, it would equal 3... Get it?

Comment: Yeah, I get it. If you use the first option suggested in my answer above, then `suitcase['sunglasses'] + suitcase['toothbrush']` will be equal `3`... Get it? :)

Comment: So I have to use "suitcase['toothbrush'] + suitcase['sunglasses']" instead of toothbrush + sunglasses?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do anything like `1 = '1'` or `int('1')`.

When you are *'setting the item of `sunglasses` to an integer so [you] can later add it'*, you should just originally set the item at that `index` of the `list` `suitcase` as an integer, like this:

```
suitcase[0] = 1  # An integer (non-real number not in quotation marks).
```

However, you should probably (it would be better to) use a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=dictionary#dictionaries) here; for example:

```
>>> suitcase = {}
>>> suitcase[1] = 'sunglasses'
>>> suitcase
{1: 'sunglasses'}
>>> suitcase[1]
'sunglasses'
```

This way, you can assign any string value to a number and call by that numerical value without having to throw away the string, in this case `'sunglasses'`.

Comment: So if I type up, on python, that "suitcase[0] = 1" It will be set as an integer or still a string? As I want to add more items to my arrays. 8 infact.

Comment: It would be an integer and items can be added to lists with `my_list.append(my_value)`. I would strongly suggest that to improve you should read up on data types and structures in Python.

Comment: On Codeacademy.com? I am checking it out, but just need to know about adding items in arrays like integers.

Comment: Check out [this](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html) and [this](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html). These are the Python docs and are incredibly useful. Read as much as you can. Seriously.

Comment: I can't upvote.... not enough rep? How do I earn that :P And I have accepted the answer

Answer (score 0):

An array is only a sequence of things, and probably cannot be used the way you have in mind.

I assume you would like to record that you have one 'sunglasses' in your suitcase.

For this you need a dictionary:

```
-> suitcase = dict()
-> suitcase['sunglasses'] = 2
-> number_of_sunglasses = suitcase['sunglasses']
-> print(number_of_sunglasses)
   1
```

Comment: No, no, no, I was thinking about adding the actual integer as being the suitcase as (Number one) and adding this....

Comment: I'm sorry, I am trying to help you but I don't understand what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old, but from my understanding, your first item in the suitcase array is "Sunglasses" and you want to replace the "Sunglasses" with "1". Here is another approach you can use

```
suitcase = []
suitcase.append("sunglasses")
>>> for n,i in enumerate(suitcase):
...   if i=='sunglasses':
...      suitcase[n]="1"
...
>>> suitcase
```